# Creating unique structures in Neo4j with them having nodes that are part of another structure

Tags: data-structures, graph, neo4j, cypher

Let's say that we have n nodes with label **:Test** and a unique property called type.

```
UNWIND[{ type:"a" }, { type:"b" }, { type:"c" }, { type:"d" }] AS x
MERGE (t:Test { type: x.type })
RETURN t
```

That looks like this

[image: Base structure]

Now let's introduce a node of label **:Collection**. The purpose if this node is to have a unique relationship pattern with the **:Test** nodes.

```
MATCH (a:Test { type:"a" }),(b:Test { type:"b" })
CREATE UNIQUE (x:Collection)-[:HAS]->(a),(x:Collection)-[:HAS]->(b)
Return *
```

[image: 1st collection]

The problem that I face starts occurring when I try to make another unique structure, like the previous one, but with some nodes in common.

```
MATCH (a:Test { type:"a" })
CREATE UNIQUE (x:Collection)-[:HAS]->(a)
RETURN *
```

The expected result is that another node of label **:Collection** gets created and linked to **:Test** **{type:"a"}** but the actual result is that it matches the previous data structure and returns that instead of creating a new one.

[image: 2nd collection]

The expected result should have 2 **:Collection** nodes, one linked to **type:"a"**, the other one linked to **type:"a"** and **type:"b"**.

[image: expected result]

Any input kind of input will be very appreciated :D

Comment: A potential quick and dirty fix is to have a unique property for **:Collection** made out of the **:Test** **type**s ordered alphanumerically. Something like **:Collection {type: "ab"}** and **:Collection {type:"a"}** and have the query rendered in that way before sending it to the Cypher parser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [neo4j docs on `CREATE UNIQUE`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-create-unique.html):

> CREATE UNIQUE is in the middle of MATCH and CREATE — it will match
>   what it can, and create what is missing. CREATE UNIQUE will always
>   make the least change possible to the graph — if it can use parts of
>   the existing graph, it will.

You add `Collection` nodes without any properties. I think if `CREATE UNIQUE` finds a `Collection` node, it will use it. This is how `CREATE UNIQUE` is supposed to work.

So if you want a new `Collection` that is linked to some `Test` nodes, you can either add some unique properties to the node:

```
MATCH (a:Test { type:"a" })
CREATE UNIQUE (x:Collection {key: 'unique value'})-[:HAS]->(a)
RETURN *
```

Or create it in a separate step:

```
MATCH (a:Test { type:"a" })
CREATE (x:Collection)
CREATE (x)-[:HAS]->(a)
RETURN *
```

Or use `MERGE` instead of `CREATE UNIQUE`.

Comment: Or actually: `MATCH (a:Test { type:"a" }), (x:Collection)
CREATE UNIQUE (x)-[:HAS]->(a)
RETURN *`